# How to update rows from an existing table using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `SP_Retrieve_Emp` which retrieves data from the table `dbo.Employees`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Retrieve_Emp]
    @BatchSize int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Return the @BatchSize records
    SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) *
    FROM dbo.[Employees]
    WHERE Status = ' '
    ORDER BY ID ASC;
END;
```

The table `dbo.Employees` has the following columns

| ID | Full_Name | Position | Email | Status | Process_Start_Time | Process_End_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John Smith | Engineer | jsmith@abc.com |  |  |  |
| 98765 | Rachel White | Admin | rwhite@abc.com |  |  |  |
| 67890 | James Larry | Manager | jlarry@abc.com |  |  |  |

When the stored procedure is executed, I want it to return the n number of rows and also be able to update the `Status` to 'Processed' and return the current timestamp on 'Process_Start_Time' in the `dbo.Employees` table.

When I run the stored procedure as shown above and set `@BatchSize = 200`, I would expect it to return 200 rows and at the same time update the `Status` to 'Processed' and `Process_Start_Time` to current timestamp to the table

| ID | Full_Name | Position | Email | Status | Process_Start_Time | Process_End_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John Smith | Engineer | jsmith@abc.com | Processed | 2022-08-26 16:14:00 |  |
| 98765 | Rachel White | Admin | rwhite@abc.com | Processed | 2022-08-26 16:14:00 |  |
| 67890 | James Larry | Manager | jlarry@abc.com | Processed | 2022-08-26 16:14:00 |  |

Can you please advise how I can include this to the stored procedure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the SQL update statement? If not I can highly recommend the documentation which will show you how to update your rows.

Comment: And you can use `@@rowcount` to capture how many rows are affected, and assign that to an output parameter (see the documentation for stored procedures).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single step, using an `OUTPUT` clause

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetrieveAndUpdateEmployees]
    @BatchSize INT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

UPDATE emp
SET Status = 'Processed',
    Process_Start_Time = SYSDATETIME()
OUTPUT inserted.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@BatchSize)
      *
    FROM dbo.Employees emp
    WHERE emp.Status = ' '
    ORDER BY emp.ID
) emp;
```

If the table has foreign keys then you must output into a table variable first.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetrieveAndUpdateEmployees]
    @BatchSize INT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @temp TABLE (Employee_Table_Schema_Here)

UPDATE emp
SET Status = 'Processed',
    Process_Start_Time = SYSDATETIME()
OUTPUT inserted.Specify_Columns_Here
  INTO @temp (Specify_Columns_Here)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@BatchSize)
      *
    FROM dbo.Employees emp
    WHERE emp.Status = ' '
    ORDER BY emp.ID
) emp;

SELECT *
FROM @temp;
```